# Are double universal (Cardan) joints exactly constant velocity?

Tags: automotive-engineering, kinematics, power-transmission, transmission, shafts

Some double universal joints use a centering joint to ensure that the angle of the input and output are equal to maintain a constant velocity through the joint.  From what I can tell, this centering joint consists of a ball joint that can slide through a slot.  It would seem to me that this arrangement would not give an exactly equal angle for the input and output at all possible angles, so is an approximately equal angle deemed acceptable? Or am I missing something about this arrangement that forces the angles to be exactly equal?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Exactness is extremely difficult to achieve in reality.  Whether things are close enough tends to be much more relevant.  Levers and gears deflect under load, but we try to design and operate those under conditions where those are relatively negligible.  What is acceptable for a CV joint, you'd have to figure from modeling - forces play a role in what the angles would be.  Gyroscopic effects might also play a role at extremely high rpms.

Comment: They are good enough rather than perfect. The angular acceleration of the coupler implies a torque variation at constant speed, or a speed variation at constant torque. But in real life use they are not bad at all.

Comment: Usually this example is worked through in many textbooks.